# При отправке команд на TCP сервер с Android получаю одинаковые ответы

Tags: android, tcp, микроконтроллеры

Смысл программы в том, чтобы получить по Wi-Fi показания с датчиков на приборе. При отправке команд получаю одинаковые значения(предыдущие), а через консоль получаю верное значение.

Подскажите, что не так? Когда подключаюсь к прибору netcat'ом, то данные приходят нормально.
Activity: http://pastebin.com/ASpznVEq
Client: http://pastebin.com/VqjyjZ22

activity:

```
package com.pmeter.dmitrij999.photometer;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;

public class Screen extends Activity {

RadioGroup scrView;
Graph_Frag graph_frag;
Console_Frag console_frag;
public client tcp_net;
FragmentTransaction fTrans;
public static String measures[];
public static String reply;
boolean measured = false;
boolean connect = false;
String ip;

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
    graph_frag = new Graph_Frag();
    console_frag = new Console_Frag();
    scrView = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.scr);
    scrView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.screen_frag);
            switch (checkedId) {
                case -1:
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No choice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.graphic:
                    //fTrans.remove(console_frag);
                    if (measured) fTrans.replace(R.id.screen_frag, graph_frag);
                    else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Невозможно показать график без измерений!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.cons:
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    fTrans.replace(R.id.screen_frag, console_frag);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            fTrans.commit();
        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        connect = false;
    }
    else {
        connect = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("connect");
    }
    Button con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    final EditText ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
    Button measure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.measure);

    //
    //
    connection();

    measure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tcp_net == null || !connect || client.getError())  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.conclosed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                int i = 0;
                measures = new String[16];
                for (i = 0;i<16;i++) measures[i] = "0";
                for (i = 0;i<16;i++) {
                    //reply = null;
                    tcp_net.sendMessage("dat" + i + "\n\r\n");
                    Log.d("Send", "dat" + i + "\n\r");
                    if (reply != null) {
                        measures[i] = reply;
                        Log.d("Meas ", " " + i + " " + reply);
                        //i++;
                    }
                }

                measured = true;
            }
        }
    });
    con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ip = ipaddress.getText().toString();
            connect = !connect;
            connection();
        }
    });
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}

public static String getMeasure(int j) {
    if (measures != null) return measures[j];
    else return null;
}

int toInt(String input) {
    int out = 0;
    int len = input.length();
    for (int l=0;l<len;l++) {
        switch (input.indexOf(l)) {
            case '0':
                break;
            case '1':
                out=out+1*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '2':
                out=out+2*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '3':
                out=out+3*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '4':
                out=out+4*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '5':
                out=out+5*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '6':
                out=out+6*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '7':
                out=out+7*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '8':
                out=out+8*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            case '9':
                out=out+9*(10^(len-l-1));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
protected void connection() {
    Button con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    connectTask cn = new connectTask();
    if (!connect) {
        con.setText(R.string.connect);
        cn.cancel(true);
    }
    else {
        cn.execute("");
        con.setText(R.string.disconnect);

        if (tcp_net != null) {
            tcp_net.sendMessage("ip?\n\r");
        }
    }
    if (client.getError()) {
        connect = false;
        con.setText(R.string.connect);
        cn.cancel(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.con_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
}

protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRestart");
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume ");
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("connect", connect);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStop");
}

public static void putRes(String msg) {
    reply = msg;
}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,client> {

    @Override
    protected client doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        tcp_net = new client(new client.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        tcp_net.Set(ip);
        tcp_net.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //reply = values[0];
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), reply, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        //arrayList.add(values[0]);
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        //tvInfo.setText("Cancel");

        //tcp_net.stopClient();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.conclosed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cancel");
    }
}
}
```

client:

```
package com.pmeter.dmitrij999.photometer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by dmitrij999 on 15.04.16.
 */
public class client {
    private String serverMessage;
    public static String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.100"; //your computer IP address
    public static int SERVERPORT = 80;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    public static boolean errors = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public client(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    public void Set(String ip) {
        SERVERIP = ip;
        //Log.d("IP", SERVERIP);
        //SERVERPORT = port;
    }
    public static boolean getError() {
        return errors;
    }
    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
            //mMessageListener.messageReceived("Connecting...");
            //
            errors = false;
            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                try {
                    //send the message to the server
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
                    //mMessageListener.messageReceived("Sent ");

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");
                    errors = false;

                    //receive the message which the server sends back
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                    //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                    while (mRun) {
                        //Thread.sleep(300);
                        serverMessage = in.readLine();

                        if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                            //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                            mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);

                            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                            Screen.putRes(serverMessage);
                        }

                        serverMessage = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived("Error " + e);
                    errors = true;
                }

                finally {
                    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
                errors = true;
                Log.e("TCP", "Словили...");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
            errors = true;
            mMessageListener.messageReceived("Error " + e);
        }
    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может, вставите код сюда, так ведь удобнее.

Comment: боюсь, код займет много места

Comment: Да, так. Но лучше было бы так и сказать, без подобной причины мало кто пойдёт по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не было такого "наложения" команд, надо реализовать отправку в отдельном UI-потоке

```
measure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { if (tcp_net == null || !connect || client.getError())  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.conclosed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                Button meas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.measure);
                meas.setEnabled(false);
                Thread ms = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        measured = false;

                        int i;
                        measures = new String[16];
                        for (i = 0;i<16;i++) measures[i] = "0";
                        reply = "0";
                        try {
                            for (i = 0;i<16;i++) {
                                tcp_net.sendMessage("dat" + i + "\n\r\n");
                                Log.d("Send", "dat" + i + "\n\r");
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
                                if (reply != null) {
                                    measures[i] = reply;
                                    Log.d("Meas ", " " + i + " " + reply);
                                }
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally {
                            measured = true;
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Button meas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.measure);
                                    meas.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
                ms.start();

            }
        }
    });
```